# Node.JS, ExpressJS, React and HTML JSON rendering

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I am a beginner in web dev and I am developping a web app using firstly Node.JS to **scrape** restaurants informations from two websites ([Maitres Restaurateurs](https://www.maitresrestaurateurs.fr/) and [Guide Michelin](https://guide.michelin.com/fr/fr/restaurants)), then ExpressJS to begin the app. I use `res.sendFile()` function to display my HTML page then `res.json()` to send a JSON file in the HTML page.

First, here is my work dir (It's a mess):

```
src
├server.js
├index.html
├server-side
 ├bib.js
├jsx
 ├react.jsx
```

`server.js` code (where i get in the `listFinal` variable a JSON object with all my restaurants informations **scraped** with puppeteer on the two website. It was done thanks to `bib.js`):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = new express();
const bib = require('./server-side/bib');
var listFinal = bib.get();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./index.html', {root: __dirname});
  res.send(listFinal);
});
  
app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!');
});
```

The server is working good. However none of my HTML or my React code is working (I'm completly new to React). The only thing displayed on my HTML is my huge JSON stored in the variable `listFinal`. The list has a length (or size) of 50 and here is its structure:

```
[{"name": "Saperlipopette ",
  "url": "www.saperlipopette1.fr",
  "address": "9 place du Théâtre, Puteaux, 92800, France",
  "price_style": "36 - 65 EUR • Cuisine moderne",
  "phone": "+33 1 41 37 00 00"},
  ...]
```

My `index.html` code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Session 3 Work - Axel Joly</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Bib gourmand + Maitre restaurateur scrappeur">
  <meta name="author" content="Axel Joly">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to the Bib Gourmand and Maitre Restaurateur list (made by Axel Joly):</h1>
  <div id="root">

    <ul id="list-rest">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="./jsx/react.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my `react.jsx` code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

export class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Welcome to React!!</h1>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As explained before, none of them are displayed.
When I run `node server.js` and go to localhost:8000/, I've got this:

[image: JSON with ExpressJS]

As you can see, there is no `<h1>` header rendered, both normally displayed with React and HTML. Also, I don't know how to "*retrive*" my variable `listFinal` in the HTML to render it as a li with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

Comment: That's probably because you haven't created a react-app and are trying to use `jsx` file to run the react code what you wanna do is create a react app via `npx create-react-app client` which would contain the client-side code then i would recommend using `concurrently` to run both the client-side and the server-side at the same time. ( i could set this up for you if you are willing to put the current code on `codesandbox` )

Comment: @AbdullahAbid Hi ! Thanks for you comment, I tried your first recommendation but I was unable to do it. I made a github repo then a codesandbox. Here it is : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-violet-yxbmc)

Comment: fyi it's __scraper__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment you are trying to run `React` via a single `JSX` file, what you want to do is to create a react app via `npx create-react-app client` which would send the request to your server-side code. So, i have modified your code and what i have done is used `concurrenlty` to run both the server-side and client-side at the same time, this is done by changing the `package.json` of the server-side.

```
"scripts": {
 "build": "next build",
 "start": "node index.js",
 "server": "node index.js",
 "client": "npm start --prefix client",
 "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
 "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
 }
```

The Next thing you want to do is send a request from your client side to your side,you can send do this by using `axios`

```
    GetData = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/`, {
        crossdomain: true
      });
   console.log(response.data); // This would log the data received from your server
   //Res of Code
```

you can check the working example [here](https://github.com/AbdullahAbid87/APIExample) (I tried using codesandbox but i was experiencing some issues there so i uploaded it on Github instead)

so to run the run the project you would open your terminal and run the following commands

```
git clone https://github.com/AbdullahAbid87/APIExample.git
cd APIExample 
npm i   
cd client  
npm i  
cd ..  
npm run dev
```

(Note: if the request to the server-side does not go through , then it is probably a `CORS` issue ,Although this might not be ideal but the simplest way to solve it would be to download a browser extension called `CORS Everywhere` that should solve it right away)

Hope this Helps